Feedback on custom "Orchestration" architecture
I've been doing some deep thinking on how to structure code and found myself coming up with a (for me) new pattern. The pattern is based on a highly modular approach with a large focus on indirection, reusability and enforcement of a singular "right way" of coding.
I have started trying the pattern out and found that the design goals are achieved. However, projects tend to become a bit complex and hard to refactor by hand due to a lot of tools using source-root relative paths. I'm therefore interested in some feedback - especially if you recognize this pattern from somewhere else!
The pattern consists of three main layers. Starting from the bottom we have
Specification
This is your typical "core" module. However, its main purpose is to declare the public interfaces that makes the application work. It should also declare the common data representation "model" that is used by the rest of the application. As a non-C programmer, this layer sounds a lot like C header files to me.
Logic should preferably not be part of the specification layer, though it's not uncommon for utils or helpers to end up here.
Implementation
Whereas the specification layer specifies the application, the implementation layer implements this specification.
The implementation layer consists of many smaller modules, each of which are highly specialized in a single area such as interacting with a certain remote API, persisting data, calculating directions, etc.. The modules should be designed like mini-libraries that implement specific parts of the interfaces defined in the specification layer. Care should also be taken to not expose implementation details publicly, e.g. by defining concrete implementations as C# internal or java "package-private".
When an implementation layer module requires features it itself does not implement (such as data storage), it should rely on dependency injection of an interface type (e.g. UserRepository) from the specification layer. This also means that while modules are free to use their own internal models, all communication between modules must happen via the common models defined in the specification layer.
Finally, implementation layer modules should expose their implementations, not by making them public (unless that's desirable) but rather by binding them to their appropriate specification layer interface via a system for dependency injection. This could for example be done by having each module expose a single ModuleInitializer which takes care of initialization and binding for the individual module.
Orchestration
At the top, the orchestration layer is used to orchestrate all of the implementation layer modules. This is where we find the program's main entrypoint.
The main purpose of the orchestration layer is to select and initialize the implementation layer modules required to run the application. This also means that a single code base can have multiple orchestration modules, e.g. if it is supposed to have a library output and an application output.
As with the specification layer, the orchestration layer should contain very little logic.
Tests
Unit tests should be placed alongside the specific module they are testing. Dependencies that are not implemented by the module can easily be mocked since the module relies only on specification layer abstractions.
Integration tests can for example be placed alongside the primary orchestration module they intend to exercise.
Naming
This pattern emphasizes the use of abstractions over concrete implementations. Therefore, it also recommends interface Car and class CarImpl over interface ICar and class Car.

EDIT
I have been asked to clarify the problem I have with this architecture and what I'm requesting feedback on:

My main issue is that the architecture results in a large number of  sub-projects. In part, this is desired, but I've also found that it makes organization and refactoring harder, especially when not using a specialized IDE such as Visual Studio (which I typically don't). I'd be interested in your thoughts on this issue as well as potential solutions.
I'm interested to know if this architectural scheme is already established and if so, under what name so that I can conduct further research.


Your question seems overly broad and opinion based.

Can you [edit] your question to clarify the problem you have with your proposed architecture? I think this question could work, but we need a more tightly focused problem to solve.

Based on the site description, I was hoping it would be ok to ask a more generalized question on the merits of this architectural scheme. @GregBurghardt I have added an edit at the end which I hope can help clear things up and narrow the question down somewhat.

I copy-pasted the question into Google Gemini and was told my architecture sounds an awful lot like Hexagonal architecture, a.k.a. Ports and Adapters. Looking it up, I would agree. My personal description emphasizes separation even more heavily by explicitly mentioning that individual parts of the application should be separated into separate modules but the overall description is the same.

Thank you for clarifying. I think this is a good question. I up-voted this myself. I did remove the last bullet point. The Q&A style of this community discourages questions asking for general feedback. They tend to get closed as needing focus or being too opinion-based. Otherwise, a good first question in my opinion.

Here's is my critique of your architecture. Bear in mind that you only give us this short questions worth of information.
It is similar to other layered architectures such as clean architecture. The key differences seem to be:
Specification/Domain/Model Layer
You have interfaces, data models and no logic. Much like an ADM approach which I think is great.
You put helpers and utils here which is very bad indeed and really goes against the rest of your pattern. Surely these should be implementations.
Implementation/Domain Logic/Service layer
Keeping modules code small and focused is good and follows SOLID principles.
Keeping all the objects private and forcing the use of Builders to create them, seems unnecessary and overly complex. What layer do the builders live in? Will it even work if the interfaces have public methods?
Orchestration/Application Layer
You don't have any other layers so I guess your actual application goes in this layer, which makes it odd that you think you can have multiple orchestration modules? It's unclear how this would work or what problem it solves.
Tests
Seems like normal tests.
Naming
You really should follow language normative naming, so interface ICar in C# and Car in Java
Notes:

My main issue is that the architecture results in a large number of sub-projects

This is generally considered a good thing.

...especially when not using a specialized IDE such as Visual Studio
(which I typically don't).

This just calls into question the entirety of you question and poses a dozen questions. Everyone uses IDEs. Are you crazy?

I'm interested to know if this architectural scheme is already
established and if so, under what name so that I can conduct further
research.

Aspects of what you describe are common, I don't see anything that stands out in your description to differentiate it from other layered approaches. Maybe the multiple Orchestration objects? Implementation hiding? Are these critical to the approach or if I do everything else but have public constructors am i still following the architecture?

does the concept seem sound or are there cracks I'm missing?

There's not enough here. You need some concept to anchor the approach. It needs to be designed to solve a specific problem.

Thank you! After reading up a bit on hexagonal architecture (and related stuff) it would seem like the primary difference is in an overly-aggressive modularization, which includes implementation hiding. What I have done so far is give each module their own "entrypoint" and have them register their internal implementations of the public interface with the DI framework. I think all of this causes more of the "application" to be placed in the "implementation" layer than you seem to have expected (see also "modulith"). I really appreciate your feedback!

Could you provide a link for ADM? I'd love to learn more but am not sure I'm finding the right material.

ADM = Anemic Domain Model?

I thought the Anemic Domain Model was considered an anti-pattern?

@FelixZY it's a popular pattern that works well given you don't actually have the needs that a rich domain provides for. Chopsticks are an anti-pattern at a steak restaurant. A fork is an anti-pattern at a pizza place.

@FelixZY martin fowler wrote an article where he called it an anti pattern, but it was an off hand comment years ago in the context of monoliths and OOP. I think its fine.

However, You are suggesting separating the data from the logic in your setup, so you would have to be happy making that argument

In fact, the wikipedia page that @FelixZY linked puts it like this: "In an anemic domain design, business logic is typically implemented in separate classes which transform the state of the domain objects. Fowler calls such external classes transaction scripts." And later says, "In his book 'Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture', Fowler noted that the transaction script pattern may be proper for many simple business applications, and obviates a complex OO-database mapping layer." So yes it comes at a cost. But it has its pros as well.
